# How to log all ssh sessions?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I'm Ubuntu 18 user for some days. Previously I used Putty in Windows and it logs all my commands in SSH:
Documents/Logs/2018-11-01_20-00-03_sshserver.log
etc.

Now I need to setup logging in Ubuntu terminal too because I'm using terminal (putty doesn't know copy/paste to another app/window).

Can anybody tell me how to turn on logging?

Thank you very much.

Comment: When you do `ssh A → B` do you want to log the commands on `A` or on `B`?

Comment: Want to log commands in my linux computer, no in server. So If I made a mistake in server, I will be able to see logs in my computer

Comment: with `ssh user@server | tee -a log.txt` you will have all output appended to a file called log.txt - but this logs all escape characters too, try it out and see if this satisfies your needs.

Comment: I'm connecting to 5-7 servers per day so I need automatically log everything. No way?

Comment: what do you mean with "putty doesn't know copy/paste to another app/window" ? haven't used putty on Ubuntu but I would assume it works like the Windows version. dont have a GUI version currently, only CLI so can't test. You can install putty on Ubuntu just `sudo apt install -y putty`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `script` command. Read `man script`.

```
script my.log
ssh A
    A stuff
    exit # on A
ssh B
    B stuff
    exit # on B
exit # end of script my.log
```

Comment: friends gave me this. What do you think? Using SSH for switches, mikrotik devices. If I connecting to servers I'm using ssh keys and passphrases.

  **ssh_logging.sh**
  #!/bin/bash
  script -f -c "ssh ${*}" "/home/rene/Documents/SSH-Logs/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M')_$1.log"
  

**~/.bashrc**
  alias ssh="/bin/bash ~/scripts/ssh/ssh_logging.sh"

Comment: Tis is not a code review site. This blob is unreadable in a comment. If you cannot figure it out don't do it